# How can I decide what fields are shown in the user registration form using the user tracker? - Tiki

Tags: tiki-wiki

I want to use the user tracker to create a registration form to collect additional user information on Tiki. I have done this by configuring the User tracker and specifying that users can register using the tracker under Admin>Login. However, I do not see where I can specify what fields on the user tracker shows up on the registration form for new users?

Answer (score 1):

Under Control panel, go to "Admin Groups", where you can select the group - "Registered", click on "Edit" and under the field:"Users Information Tracker Fields Asked at Registration Time" , specify the fields you want to show up for new users registering on the registration form.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [User Trackers profile](https://profiles.tiki.org/User_Trackers) which sets up an example tracker and adds some of the fields to the registration page for you.

**N.B.** However, as usual, profiles cannot be undone easily (yet) so try this on an example empty Tiki first (e.g. https://demo.tiki.org/16x) and not your production site to be safe.

Comment: Thanks Jonny for your comment.